# develop an instant messaging in java EE (JSF)

Tags: jakarta-ee

hi I want to create an instant messenger but the problem is that I don't know where to start or I've seen a lot of tutorials but it's in java SE

do we also use java socket ee? if so how does this work for messaging?

what tools will I need?

if there is a framework or a library... I'm a taker

I'm in internship and I need to develop an instant chat application

thank you for your answers

Comment: I don't want to be impolite, but honestly... Please take a minute to think about your question. First of all, the title is in French. That attracts people like me, but you have to be aware that 95% of all StackOverflow users don't speak French. They won't read your English text because they already know from the title of your post that they won't understand anything.

Comment: Second, StackOverflow is a platform dedicated to answering advanced technical questions. Your question is, well, sort of broad - something like "please write an application for me". I know that's now what you're asking, but chances are this is what the readers read. Please take that into account next time you're asking something on StackOverflow. Mind you: everybody answering you is spending precious leisure time. Please see to it that spending leisure time is worth the effort.

Comment: you're right and I was pretty desperate not to realize what I'm trying to do and thanks for the rules and politeness and for the pull I just forgot to rewrite it in English am sorry basic question or not it remains a problem to solve everyone is not advance in programming or have the right information to develop what we want with the best adapted techno

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you've already settled on JSF, so it's out of question there's no other framework than BootsFaces.

OK, I'm a BootsFaces committer. I'm told that BootsFaces is a good choice, but of course, PrimeFaces - or even plain JSF - are good alternatives.

Concerning WebSockets, that's a hot trace. At this point, I guess you're in JavaScript country. Opening a WebSocket in JavaScript is simple. So is listening to it. To integrate with the JSF framework, you can use `<b:remoteCommand>` (BootsFaces) or `<p:remoteCommand>` (PrimeFaces). There's also an OmniFaces alternative: `<o:commandScript />`.

Hope that helps. Your question is so broad there are zillions of answers to it. Maybe I've helped you to pose better question :).

That said, I wonder why you've settled on JSF. If I were to chose the technology I liked best, I'd probably chose Vue.js, React.js or Angular 6+, in that order.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I'm not very familiar with the js but I at least managed to do something pretty similar if I answer late it's because I first gave up the project now I'm back stronger